# Relation randomly raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Once in a while when trying to fetch an order record for a particular user, a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is raised.

Some things to note here.

- The error is raised when visiting `/orders/:id`, but not for all users. We track completed orders (meaning that you end up on a orders page) and around 50% gets a 404. Note that we're talking about 50% of the users, not the requests. If it displays 404 once for an order for a particular user, it will always display a 404.
- The record exists as it can be accessed via the console using the same data that's being logged in the controller.
- The problem disappears when re-deploying the application.

What could the problem be?

I'm running rails 4.2.0.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  #
  # GET /orders/:id
  #
  def show
    Rails.logger.info "current_user=#{current_user.id}, params[:id]=#{params[:id]}"
    @order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
  end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @_current_user ||= User.find_by_id(cookies.signed[:uid])
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :orders, through: :subscriptions
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here's the log output

```
[User#id=2454266]   Parameters: {"id"=>"1553"}
[User#id=2454266] current_user=2454266, params[:id]=1553 <==== Rails.logger.info
[User#id=2454266] Completed 404 Not Found in 240ms
[User#id=2454266]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order with 'id'=1553):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:6:in `show'
```

Running `User.find(2454266).orders.find(1553)` in the console works.

Also note that it's possible to skip the relation and go directly to the order model, like this

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  #
  # GET /orders/:id
  #
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I am very interested on what gets written to your logger for that record.
I think the way you fetch the user is problematic.

Comment: Can you post the log please

Comment: I've added some logs and also a console example.

Comment: It is possible that rails caches the `has_many` query on `current_user`, check if that is the case with
`current_user.orders(true).find(params[:id])`

Comment: @xlembouras That might very well be the case. I'll try it and come back.

Comment: @xlembouras I cant say for sure, but it looks like it works. I'll let it go for a few days to make sure it works. I'll keep you in the loop.

Comment: @xlembouras Sorry, but it didn't work. Just got another 404.

Comment: Just curious... I was just wondering if there are callbacks updating current_user in between? Did you try isolating whether it might be a case of outdated data from current_user? I.e. Skip the current_user.orders and going straight to Order.find or something of sorts?

Comment: @Mingsheng I'll give it a try. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Mingsheng Going directly to the `Order` model works. Really strange.

Comment: At least we found the root of the problem. Seems like its due to something relating to current_user. Have you verified that there are no callbacks affecting it? Else it's probably some rails cache, hopefully someone can come along and provide an answer. :)

Comment: @Oleander oh yes can you try current_user.reload?

Comment: @Mingsheng Sure. I've added the code. I just have to wait for a few orders.

Comment: @Oleander do note that simply doing Order.find loses the logic on restricting orders only to be read by current_user though unless it's not a requirement. Else I can just look at the orders of others. Whereas User.find.orders.find introduces null pointer possibility. Actually so does the original... Probably current_user.reload!, User.orders.find!(id) and checking for a nil is better. I suspect it's @_current_user is an outdated instance... But I'm not 100% certain

Comment: @Mingsheng I'm currently using an md5 hash based on some of the record params to look up the record.

Comment: @Mingsheng Using `reload` solved the problem. Feels bit like magic, but hey it works :) Write an answer to this question and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to receive appreciation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we arrived at the conclusion can be found by going through the comments list.

Our summary of findings are:

1. Either orders are cached, or current_user is outdated (along with cached associations)
2. Going straight to order works (i.e. Order.find / User.find(current_user.id).orders...

Solution that we arrived at is:

```
current_user.reload!
```

Before performing

```
current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    @_current_user ||= User.find_by_id(cookies.signed[:uid])
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    @_current_user.present?
  end
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
 def show
   if user_signed_in?
     @order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
   else
    return redirect_to <404 page or any>, alert: 'Order not found'
   end
 end
end
```

I think you have to check the presence of the user first, then you can trace the bug

I usually use this method when I got some issue

```
def show
  if user_signed_in?
    begin
      @order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
    rescue => e
      binding.pry
    end
  else
   return redirect_to <404 page or any>, alert: 'Order not found'
  end
end
```

but you need 'rails-pry' gem, the advantage is rails will fire up rails console when there is exception

Comment: That's being check else were and would also rise a nil exception, not a 404 on the order object.